# Nuget package config.transform not updating appSettings

Tags: nuget-package

I created a local Nuget feed and created a package with one dll and a web.config.transform file. The web config transform file looks like this:

```
 <appSettings>
   <add key="adBasePath" value="somestring" />
   <add key="adGroupPath" value="anotherstring" />
 </appSettings>
```

When I install the package, it doesn't update the appSettings section with these entries, it adds them to the configuration section.

What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. I needed to do this:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="adBasePath" value="somestring" />
  <add key="adGroupPath" value="anotherstring" />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```